# R: read table with multiple separators and parantheses?

Tags: r

I have received this type of table, [available also here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc4fa1commm2mb0/mySample.csv?dl=0)

[image]

I wonder, how to efficiently open the table in R?

My output should be splitted in 3 separate columns, and without the parentheses: :

```
      id   type  V1  
1 13242924 'SA'  1 
2 13035909 'SA'  1 
3 6685553  'SA'  1 
4 12990163 'SA'  1
```

For now, I was thinking to split it in few steps:

- open the file as .csv with `\t` separator,
- use multiple `gsub()` to replace both parentheses,
- split the first column in two, etc.

Isn't there a simpler way? Also, seems that `optim$V1 <- gsub('(', "", optim$V1)` simply does not remove parantheses.

```
df<- read.csv("C:/sample.csv",
               sep =  "\t",
               header = F)

# Replace the parantheses:
optim$V1 <- gsub('(', "", optim$V1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to read it in using `readLines()`, clean it up and then read it in again with `read.table()`.

```
txt <-  readLines("C:/sample.csv")

read.table(text = gsub("[()\",\t]", " ", txt))

        V1 V2 V3
1 13242924 SA  1
2 13035909 SA  1
3  6685553 SA  1
4 12990163 SA  1
5 13243126 SA  1
6 12941091 SA  1
7 12939233 SA  1
8 13242835 SA  1
9  6685130 SA  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, (Not sure if we can do something while data load, but below method you definitely use post data load)

```
library(dplyr)

(d <- tibble(id = c("(123","(24"),
            type = c("'sa')", "'sa')")))

d %>% mutate_at(vars(id, type), ~str_remove_all(.x, pattern = "\\(|\\)"))
```

**using base R**

```
gsub("\\(", "", d$id)
```

Note: you need to use escape character for parentheses. see [here](http://edrub.in/CheatSheets/cheatSheetStringr.pdf).